# How to abort just one request in rest-assured framework?

Tags: java, request, httprequest, rest-assured, abort

How to abort just one request in 'rest-assured' framework?

For example, in 'apache' we could do after executing:

```
 request.abort();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do time out like this. or is there is a specific case when you want to abort?

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(5000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
                .setSocketTimeout(5000).build();

        HttpClientConfig httpClientFactory = HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                .httpClientFactory(() -> HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build());

        RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().httpClient(httpClientFactory);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I need it for a specific case. And I've tried to use such code, but got error:

Cannot cast object 'org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient@156324b' with class 'org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient' to class 'org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient'

Comment: I know that I could use a deprecated configuration, but this configuration works for all requests.